# BackgroundWorker crashes if reporting progress

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker that calls a method in a class. The method is given a reference to the BackgroundWorker so that it can report back its progress. This pseudocode shows the outline:

```
void BackgroundWorker_DoWork( object sender )
{
    BackgroundWorker w = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    var c = new ProcessingClass()
    c.someMethod( w )
}

class ProcessingClass()
{
    someMethod( BackgroundWorker w )
    {
        w.ReportProgress(50)
        //calculations...
    }
}
```

The problem is that when doing the "calculations" after reporting the progress, the program will crash. the debugger jumps to `Application.Run( new frmMain() );` in the startup "Program" class, reason given "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

If I don't report the progress, everything works fine. Does anyone know why? My guess is that this has something to do with threads, but I don't see how.

Comment: Are you sure that "w" is not null?

Comment: I think you need to show the code for your calculations.

Comment: It could be an error in your `ProgressChanged` event handler. If you empty it, does it work? Also, having the type of the exception and the full stack trace would definitely help.

Comment: More code or inner exception details please

Comment: Have you set bw.WorkerReportsProgressto true? Have you hooked event handler?

Comment: If you're getting "This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress" then it would be you haveent set reports progress - whats in your progress changed code?

Comment: Biggles, have you stepped through your background worker code?

Comment: KooKiz: Yes, this lead me to the solution (see below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some suggestions:

1.) Inspect the [`InnerException` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) of the `TargetInvocationException` exception.

2.) Configure Visual Studio to stop as soon as the exception is thrown:

[image]

This should help getting closer to the error.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the exact place and solve the problem! Here's the solution: ProgressChange read from UserState which I had not set, causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you assume that ReportProgress is blocking and prepares something on which the code in `// calculations ...` depends upon. Not that it's *not* blocking:

> The call to the ReportProgress method is asynchronous and returns immediately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this, but it's not the problem in this case.